# Airflow 2 - Creating 2 dynamic tasks within a TaskGroup that finish before the next 2 dynamic tasks start

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have the below TaskGroup that creates 2 dynamic tasks from a dictionary one to `s3` and then after that runs the `snowflake` task begins. I want to have the first 2 tasks run, regardless if they fail or not, before the next 2 tasks in this TaskGorup starts:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': START_DATE,
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'task_concurrency': 1}

with TaskGroup(group_id='ID') as ID:
    [GooglexOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id=f'{sheet_name}_s3',
        trigger_rule="all_done",
        url=True)

     >> SnowflakeLoadOperator(
        dag=dag,
        task_id=f'{sheet_name}_snowflake',
        table=CoreTable()
        )
    ) for sheet_name, config in id_sheets.items()]
```

I tried to add chain(*[GooglexOperator( .. etc)]) but still all the `s3` tasks in this TaskGroup ran at the same time.

Comment: The `task_concurrency` parameter controls the number of _total_ tasks that can be in the `running` state for a single DAG - I don't think you can set it at a `taskgroup` level.  Do tasks run one at a time in the GooglexOperator taskgroup? The best way to proceed might be to separate out some of those S3 tasks into their own task groups.

Comment: @VirajParekh to your question, they currently don't run one at a time, that is what I would like to happen, there are 30 tasks total, 15 for the s3 and 15 for the snowflake task. I want only the 1st set of s3 and snowflake tasks to run, then the next, etc until all 30 have finished.
Also, yes you're right about task_concurrency, I removed it from the task parameter and into default args. I've also updated the question to show it how I currently have it

Answer (score 0):

With the task_concurrency parameter the way that it is, are you getting the behavior you desire? If not, you can also use [airflow pools](https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-pools) to throttle the number of tasks that run at a time.

Also, Airflow might be reading your tasks weirdly. Try setting your dependencies like [tg1] >> [tg2]

Comment: I'll try pools, but regarding your commend 'try setting dependencies"  I'm not sure how to do that specifically for this TaskGroup that has 2 dynamic task_ids that create multiple tasks

Comment: Let me know how it goes! As far as dependencies go, I'd try adding the tasks with the dynamic ids to an array and setting the whole array dependent on the downstream one.

Comment: Is there a sample regarding the last comment you mentioned? how would it look is my question. and I created a pool set to 1 and had that for the s3 task and it worked